# Passing JS variable consisting of content from a JSON into d3.json function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

I'm using the D3.js Drag and Drop, Zoomable, Panning, Collapsible Tree with auto-sizing as shown here : http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033

As given in the example here, the dndTree.js has a function d3.json which takes the JSON file location as a parameter ( in this case - "flare.json" ) :

```
treeJSON = d3.json("flare.json", function(error, treeData) {

// Calculate total nodes, max label length
var totalNodes = 0;
var maxLabelLength = 0;
```

Since my JSON file is being created dynamically, I want to store this JSON into a JS variable, and pass this variable into the function and form the tree.

So far, I was able to fetch the JSON data, parse it and store it in a JS variable, but when I pass this variable into the d3.json function instead of the file, the function is not able to recognize the variable ( console.log results in undefined ) contents and since it cannot read any JSON content, it doesn't create the tree.

Any suggestion as to how I could pass this variable into the function to create the tree?

Comment: It's best to show the code how you do that: how is variable generated and used.

Comment: Can you show a sample of your json structure? This is going to dictate how you should map the tree.

Comment: I fetch my JSON file and store it in my JS variable:
var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhReq.open("GET", "/folder/file.json", false);
xhReq.send(null);
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(xhReq.responseText);

When I use console.log(jsonObject) after this, it prints the entire JSON in a valid format.

I pass this variable into the d3.json function:

treeJSON = d3.json(jsonObject, function(error, treeData) {



When I use console.log(jsonObject) inside function, it results in undefined, hence does not create the tree. 
Any way I can pass the var to make d3.json read it correctly and create the tree?

Comment: The JSON structure is similar to what they have shown in the example (flare.json) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call `d3.json` in this case -- in the example code you've posted, `treeData` holds the parsed JSON. If you have that already, all you need to do is call the variable you store it in `treeData`.

Comment: You mean I have to replace treeData with jsonObject?

Comment: Yes. `treeData` holds the JSON.

Comment: So I tried this :

treeJSON = function(error, jsonObject) {

    // Calculate total nodes, max label length
    var totalNodes = 0;
    var maxLabelLength = 0;
    // variables for drag/drop
    var selectedNode = null;

... 


...



But it gives an error at this line : root.x0 = viewerHeight / 2;
Saying cannot determine viewerHeight of undefined.

Comment: Delete the line with `d3.json` in it and the line that closes the corresponding parentheses. In the block inside the function, use the variable that you stored the JSON in instead of `treeData`. You don't need a function call to get the JSON.